# Making a client's website live with a customized domain name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hosting

I'm trying to make a website for a client right now, and I'm using Sublime Text to build it from Scratch using JQuery, JavaScript, HTML5, and CSS3.

However, I don't know how to make it live with a custom domain name when it's built from scratch. Furthermore, I need to make sure the client is paying for any monthly fees that may occur.

Finally, should I switch to only building websites with customizing site building tools like WordPress or SquareSpace? I haven't seen many tutorials on how to host a website after bulding it from scratch for a client.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Google : **How to publish a website tutorial**. There are many tutorials out there to walk you through the process.

That said, the basic process is as follows.

1. Register a domain name using a registrar of choice.
2. Purchase a hosting plan from a host of choice.
3. Bind your domain to the new hosting account (your host will have a help section for this)
4. Follow the help section for that host to get your FTP client configured. You will use this to push the files from your computer to the server.
5. Your website is now live.

Answer (score 0):

What was answered above is 100% correct, but let's give you a more detail.

1. You need to find hosting. There are lots of free resources out there, but you should be cautious. My recommendation would be something like https://getforge.com/
2. Once you have the site uploaded, you want to test it and make sure it is working in a production environment. i.e. no broken links, missing images, etc...
3. Now lets assume you have a domain already, if not you want to register one (typically $12USD per year for a .com).
4. Once the domain is secured, you will need to point the domain to your hosting company. More often than not it's best to let the domain registrar manage the DNS, and just change the IP address the A record for the domain to the new hosting account you setup in step 1.
5. Last but not least, pretty much every hosting service has an option to add on domains, or add a custom domain. This is pretty simple typically.
6. Now it will take some time for the change you made in step 4 to propagate. Have no fear, if everything was done correctly, you will have a live site now!

More advanced model of this would be how I launch static sites.

1. Build site on my local machine and setup a git repository
2. Push my local repository to Bitbucket
3. Set up continuous deployment a CDN like Netlify
4. Point the domain
5. Assign the domain to the deployment on Netlify,
6. Go have cocktails